# getDhcpInfo obtaining wrong ip Address in android

Tags: android

I need a little assistance.I'm trying to get the gateway and subnet mask details of a wifi network programmatically in android,then use the acquired string elsewhere in my application.I found a solution on this site and it's what i have implemented so far.But the ip Address returned on the device is different from when i check ipconfig on my computer.So my app crashes.
when i execute ipconfig i get 192.168.0.xx5, but on my activity on the textview display a different one is shown  192.168.0.xx1..But since i am downloading data from my xampp server, i need it to be the same.

Below is my code:

```
public class DHCPInfo extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
public String   s_dns1 ;
public String   s_dns2;     
public String   s_gateway;  
public String   s_ipAddress;        
public String   s_subnet;  
public String   s_serverAddress;


TextView dhcp_info,ip_address;

Button btn_dhcp;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
DhcpInfo dhcpInfo;
WifiManager wifii;

final Handler h = new Handler();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dhcp);



    wifii= (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    dhcpInfo=wifii.getDhcpInfo();

    s_dns1="DNS 1: "+String.valueOf(dhcpInfo.dns1);
    s_dns2="DNS 2: "+String.valueOf(dhcpInfo.dns2);    
    s_gateway="Default Gateway: "+String.valueOf(dhcpInfo.gateway);    
    s_ipAddress="IP Address: "+String.valueOf(dhcpInfo.ipAddress);     
    s_subnet="Subnet Mask: "+String.valueOf(dhcpInfo.netmask);    
    s_serverAddress="Server IP: "+String.valueOf(dhcpInfo.serverAddress);




    int ipAddress = dhcpInfo.ipAddress;
    intToIpAddress(ipAddress);



    //display them
    dhcp_info= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_dhcp);
    dhcp_info.setText("Network Info\n"+s_dns1+"\n"+s_dns2+"\n"+s_gateway+"\n"+s_ipAddress+"\n"+s_serverAddress);

    ip_address= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_ip);
    dhcp_info.setText("IP Address\n"+ intToIpAddress(ipAddress));

    btn_dhcp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_dhcp);
    btn_dhcp.setOnClickListener(this);


}

 public String intToIpAddress(int ipAddress) {
    return  ((ipAddress & 0xFF) + "." + 
            ((ipAddress >>>= 8) & 0xFF) + "." + 
            ((ipAddress >>>= 8) & 0xFF) + "." + 
            ((ipAddress >>>= 8) & 0xFF));
}
}
```

Comment: Is your computer your gateway?

Comment: @Deacoy ,no i don't think so.Because i just connect my device directly into the wifi network though my xampp server is hosted on my computer.so i'm a little confused.

Comment: `But the ip Address returned on the device is different from when i check ipconfig on my computer.`  Because your device and your computer are different nodes on the network and have different IP addresses.

Comment: @Pedantic okay.I understand that now.thank you.So can you help me understand how i a get it to work?I want my android application to be able to programmatically access the wifi network.Which it does,i guess.But my challenge is how to get it to access the server or return the same ip address as the server

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you have a laptop and a mobile device. Both are connected to the same WiFi network and your laptop is working as a web server. It is normal that they have different IP addresses - since they are different devices after all. :)

If your router is giving static IPs to the devices (that's unlikely) you could just hardcode the address of your laptop in the Java code. This is more or less OK for debugging but useless for production - since application will work only when you have a device connected to your present WiFi network.

Alternatively, you could make your web application accessible on Internet (instead of just using the local network). If your ISP is giving you a static IP, you could host the application on your laptop. Otherwise you could use some hosting provider - some cloud service should be an OK solution too and pretty cheap.

Comment: Yes,you totally understand my question :-) .The ISP gives dynamic IP addresses..That was where i got stuck.Could you tell me more about making my application public on the internet-using the cloud service,or perhaps even a tutorial that could elaborate more..because i want other users,not within my network to be able to   access the files on my server.

Comment: Sorry for the slow answer. :) There are a number of cloud services. Some of the most popular are https://www.heroku.com/ , https://developers.google.com/appengine/?csw=1 , http://aws.amazon.com/ . They aren't very expensive (could be used for free with some constrains). The usage depends on the cloud you choose and the type of application you want to deploy. Initially you'd have to check which clouds support your application (be PHP, Java, .Net and so on), since most clouds support only a limited number of platforms. :)

Comment: okay.I kind of get what you mean :-).But assume you're talking to a complete newbie,which i am.I have been testing on my emulator,and able to access the wifi and i can also do the same on my phone when it is connected to my laptop.How do i move from this stage to making my server public for users who aren't on the same network?